# Removing / and .php but keeping the rest of the URL with $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Tags: php

I don't really know how to ask this question, but I'm trying to do something with my website, I've already removed `.php` and the `/` from `PHP_SELF`, but the thing is, I have a page that is called `profile`, and if you have for example `profile?username=ImSchnebz`, I want to keep that on the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Could you reformulate your question with one example? It is not really clear what you want. example.com/profile.php?username=ImSchnebz should change to example.comprofile?username=ImSchnebz?

Comment: @MatthiasS Okay, basically, I have a login button, so when you click that, it sets the url to `echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php');`
So basically, when I am on the index page, it would set the login url to be login?redirect=index, but what I want, is that if you're checking a public profile, which would be for example `profile?username=ImSchnebz` then if you click the login button it won't keep login?redirect=profile, but it will say login?redirect=profile?username=ImSchnebz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand what your question is but maybe you should take a look at `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` instead of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

Answer (score 0):

While it seems to me a bad idea to do so, the following code should do what you want to do:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = current(explode('.', end(explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))));
```